# Flink Kafka: Gracefully close flink consuming messages from kafka source after a time interval when no messages are received

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming

I have added flinkkafkaconsumer as source to my streamexecutionenvironment. I would like to close/stop flink from consuming data when no new messages are received for a specific time(similar to kafka polltime). 
Currently it is running indefinitely and blocking the execution from moving to next step(validating the messages).
Please suggest if there is any workaround.

Note: I tried with endofstream from deserialization and it wont work since stream is practically indefinite.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for testing, then one approach is to create your own custom Source that "wraps" the `FlinkKafkaConsumer`. Your source's `run()` method would call the Kafka source's `run()` method from a thread, passing in a collector that wraps the real collector, and updates a "last collected time" whenever anything is collected. In your source's `run()` method you would then poll on this, and call the Kakfa source's `cancel()` method when too much time has elapsed, then exit as well.

Having said all that, typically for unit testing you'd want to use a mocked source that lets you control exactly what's being generated, and when, versus spinning up a Kafka system.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It helped.